# Migrating an application from prototype 1.5 to 1.7

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am migrating an application from prototype 1.5 to prototype 1.7.
 Has anyone already had an experience with this migration?
 Please share the pain points that I may face while doing this migration.

Thanks,

Comment: I upgraded from 1.6 to 1.7 and there was absolutely nothing that broke. 1.7 actually fixed Scriptaculous sliders in IE9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I completed the upgradation everything worked fine.
http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/upgrading
This feature is really helpful.